# Applying for B1/B2 from Bangkok as Indian

Tags: indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, thailand, bangkok

I plan to be in Thailand for 2 months. I intend to get my US B1/B2 visa done there while I am there.

Is it advisable? If someone has been through this scenario, can you share your experience? What are some additional things that one needs to consider?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Will two months be enough to get an interview though? As a non-resident you'll probably be behind residents in the interview schedule... Also, how are you planning to stay 2 months in Thailand? Are you applying for an Indian visa? Or are you banking on getting 30 days visa-free twice?